# Is 302 redirection secure? Can it be intercepted?

Tags: security, redirect

If the browser requests a resource X which returns 302 and redirects the browser to Y using some parameters in get, is there a way in javascript or manually in the browser to change this parameters?

So basically :

1. browser requests X
2. browser receives 302 location Y?pp1=value1
3. browser requests Y?pp1=value1

Is it possible to change value1 in any way before the browser sends it?

Comment: Yes. I could, for example, use `curl` to get the location header from #1 without actually hitting the URL that's returned.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course, any end user can use a tool like [Burp Suite](https://portswigger.net/burp) intercepting proxy to change the request URL at Step 3.

Also, if the requests are over plain HTTP rather than HTTPS, a Man-In-The-Middle could change the request URL in Step 3.

To protect against the first situation, don't trust anything from the client that could gain them advantage if changed.

To protect against the section, use HTTPS with HSTS policy to prevent downgrade.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I meant more if this is possible using a Xss attack or other similar ways.

Comment: If there's XSS an attacker can redirect the browser wherever he or she likes.

Comment: Yes sure. But let's say that the attacker wants to let the browser call the giving-302 api and only when the browser has the response of that call, he want to redirect the user (using the response info). Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, the XSS would have to capture whatever causes the browser to request at stage (1). For example, adding a handler to the button or link the user clicks. The XSS script would then send its own request for the same URL and then do whatever it wants with the response.

Comment: Can you provide a little example with javascript, how to update the url returned with status 302, before the browser calls that?
I was not able with javascript to call url XXX(which returns 302 url YYYY) and doing anything else before I get the response of YYYY. Basically I cannot intercept the 302 response.